# Calling Functions from a Pointer Vector

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am just new to C++, so bear with me.  Inside my class, `MyArena`, I made a vector of pointers, `fighters`, of another class, `Fighter`.  With this vector, I am collecting Fighter pointers and calling functions for them.  But I keep getting errors for `fighters`.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
class Fighter;

class MyArena {

    vector<Fighter*> fighters;
    int current_size = 0;

    bool MyArena :: addFighter(string info){

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
            if (fighters[i]->getName() == n) //error that "point to incomplete pass type is not allowed?"
                isLegit = false;
        }

        fighters.push_back(new Fighter(n, t, mH, st, sp, m)); //"Fighter" is incomplete type?
        return true;
    }

    bool removeFighter(string name){
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
            if (fighters[i]->getName() == name)//error that "point to incomplete pass type is not allowed?"
                fighters[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

};
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: `Fighter` is not defined. Move the member function definitions out of the header and into a `.cpp` file.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers` See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forward declare the class here:

```
class Fighter;
```

But you never included the file. Put this after your other include

```
#include "Fighter.h"
```

Or a relative path to get to `Fighter.h` if it is in a different folder.

Comment: Yep, I forgot to #include the class.